# How to remove multiple items in JList

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlist

It's funny, I can't find out how to delete multiple selected items in a JList

Help please

[image]

**UPD:**
OK, the problem was in NetBeans, because it creates JList and sets model `AbstractListModel` which somehow not working with remove method.

Comment: It is funny that you didn't look at the JList javadoc :-)  http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedIndices()

Comment: @StephenC it's funny cause NetBeans creates AbstractListModel and foo.remove(i); not working at this case.

Comment: @StephenC Glad I made you little happier today :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
   DefaultListModel dlm = (DefaultListModel) subjectList.getModel();

      if(this.subjectList.getSelectedIndices().length > 0) {
          int[] selectedIndices = subjectList.getSelectedIndices();
          for (int i = selectedIndices.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
              dlm.removeElementAt(selectedIndices[i]);
          } 
    }
```

Comment: The key that I found to implementing the above answer is that you need to use the [`JList(ListModel<E> dataModel)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#JList(javax.swing.ListModel)) constructor, otherwise your model is read-only.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this problem too.
All posted solutions did not work for me because if I call DefaultListModel#remove(int) it will modify the underlying list and thus the indices which I gathered before with JList#getSelectedIndices() are no longer valid.

I came to this solution, which worked for me.

```
for (MyObject o : jList1.getSelectedValuesList())
{
    ((DefaultListModel<MyObject>)jList1.getModel()).removeElement(o);
}
```

By handling the selected Objects I don't have to care about indices and their validity.

Comment: If you start from the last/end of the selected list, you should be able to remove the items by index without hitting ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception... even though the underlying list keep changing after every removal the indices of items at the beginning of the list would not change if you start from the back..

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
DefaultListModel dlm = (DefaultListModel) lst.getModel();
int count = lst.getSelectedIndices().length;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
     dlm.removeElementAt(lst.getSelectedIndex());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] getSelectedIndices()
```

Answer (score -1):

where `foo` is the JList:

```
int[] selected = foo.getSelectedIndices();
for(int i : selected){
  foo.remove(i);
}
```